# template variable in Prometheus recording rules

Tags: prometheus

I am stuck with an issue related to Prometheus recording rules.

Below is my problem statement.

We have an inbuilt alerting system which is monitoring and firing the alerts. Now we have integrated our Kubernetes cluster with the system for alerting purpose. On Kubernetes I have multiple nodes, we created structure like all of our applications metrics are getting stored on Prometheus and our application query the Prometheus for fetching the value. Basically we are providing two information to the alerting application one the actual value and other the flag 0 / 1 for alerting purpose. As show below

Number of cluster node can be from 1 to 20 as of now.

A sample recording rule is as below, N can be 1 to 20

**record:system_node_[N]*cpu_utilization
expr:(100 - (avg by(kubernetes_node) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{kubernetes_node="Node_name",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100))
record:system_node*_[N]_high_cpu_utilization_alarm
expr:(100 - (avg by(kubernetes_node) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{kubernetes_node="Node_name",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)) > bool 80**

My application cannot pass the Node_name and other challenge I see is my cluster can have single node or multiple node depending upon the requirement, so I cannot hard code the value for the node name.

My question here is can we create any variable and pass it in place of node name in the recording rules or what is the possible way to pass these variables.